# PyQT5 doesn't prompt to overwrite when a default suffix is used

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm using PyQT5 on Ubuntu 23.10 (GNOME 45 on Wayland).

I would like `QFileDialog` to prompt for overwrite if the user typed a file name without suffix, which would exist if the default suffix is applied to it (e.g.: `image` turns into `image.png` which would overwrite the existing `image.png` file).

The current behavior prompts **only** if the user selected an existing file or typed it with a suffix. If the user clicks `Replace` on the popup, then both the popup as well as the dialog are closed and the dialog is accepted. If the user clicks `Cancel` on the popup, only the popup is closed.

This behavior is even more problematic if I have to deal with multiple filters (e.g.: `Images (*.png);; Text (*.txt)`), for which I think I'd need to add a listener to `QFileDialog.setNameFilter` that updates the default suffix with `QFileDialog.setDefaultSuffix`, but I couldn't find an event/signal like `filterChanged`.

How can I change `QFileDialog` to:

1. Prompt the user if they would select a file that would overwrite another one with its suffix?
2. Automatically change the default suffix.

I tried subclassing `QFileDialog`, but if `setDefaultSuffix` was called, then the suffix is already appended as well as the dialog is already closed by the time `dialog.accept()` is called, so I can only reject it.

```py
import os, re

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class QFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def accept(self):
        """This is run after dialog is closed.
        """
        path = next(iter(self.selectedFiles()), "")
        filter = self.selectedNameFilter()
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)

        if path and not ext:
            match = re.search(r'\*(\.[\w\.]+)', filter)
            if match:
                ext = match[1]
                path += ext

                if os.path.exists(path) and not self.askOverwrite(path):
                    return super().reject()

        return super().accept()

    def askOverwrite(self, path):
        """Replicate the popup asking to overwrite a file."""
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)

        msg_box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
        msg_box.setText(f'A file named "{filename}" already exists. Do you want to replace it?')
        msg_box.setInformativeText(f'The file already exists in "{os.path.basename(dirname)}". Replacing it will overwrite its contents.')
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes)
        msg_box.setDefaultButton(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return msg_box.exec_() == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("File exporter")
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Export!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def save_file(self, filter):
        dialog = QFileDialog(self, "Save as...", "", filter=filter)
        dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)

        match = re.search(r'\*(\.[\w\.]+)', filter)
        if match:
            dialog.setDefaultSuffix(match[1])

        if dialog.exec_() == QFileDialog.Accepted:
            file = next(iter(dialog.selectedFiles()), None)
        else:
            print("rejected")
            file = None
        return file


    def onClicked(self):
        print("\nclicked!")
        file = self.save_file("Image files (*.png)")
        print("Export this", file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Edit: added minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `accept` is not called after the dialog is closed. In fact, it's exactly *its* responsibility to eventually close it or not. I don't know what you were looking for, but QFileDialog *does* provide a signal that is emitted whenever the filter is changed, and it's [`filterSelected`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#filterSelected). Please provide a [mre] of your attempt, as I'm under the impression that you're trying to do the above while using the static functions, for which subclassing is completely useless.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example. When `accept` is run, there are two possible cases given I typed a file without suffix: (1) if I didn't exec `setDefaultSuffix`, then it will show my custom popup after the file dialog is closed; (2) if I did exec `setDefaultSuffix`, then it will already have the file with the extension, so I cannot check if the user has actually agreed to overwrite their file. In both cases, the default overwrite prompt that should appear when I type a file with an extension doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `filterSelected`, my vision is not very good, so I read it as `fileSelected` in the docs lol

Comment: Ok, I see that you're using the proper constructor, but do you know that by default QFileDialog uses the *native* file dialog (provided by the OS)? This is [explained in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#details) and while it allows a more *native* look with the current OS, also limits access to QFileDialog functions and features (including some of its signals), and in *that* case, `accept` may be actually called too late, because Qt has almost no control on what the dialog does until it returns control back to it. I suggest you to try the `DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Comment: I see... I really like the native look though (I have to deal with some java apps with really ugly file dialogs). Is there any place that I could report or get in contact with the devs? The default behavior of `setDefaultSuffix` really looks like a bug to me, and I couldn't find a github to report it.

Comment: It's not a bug, in the sense that Qt can only work with what the system provides. If it allows it to connect the system file dialog features to its signals and capabilities, it does it, otherwise there's nothing it can do. When the dialog is created, Qt loses almost all control over it, its behavior, and what the user does in the meantime, until the dialog is finally closed. As said, if you want more control over the file dialog, the only option is to not use the native one.

Comment: I agree that it's the expected behavior as far as the current functionality allows. But I still think that it could be reported so that it can be improved. Within Ubuntu, I think that Qt asks for GNOME's file picker to use under QFileDialog, so maybe GNOME's implementation could add one or multiple "suffix hints" to indicate that a default suffix will be added, so the user should be aware that the file is going to be overwritten. Since the QFileDialog already returns a path with the suffix added, this should improve its usability.

Comment: I don't know if Ubuntu uses the standard Gnome file dialog or it uses/extends it with their own implementation. You could report that anyway, probably looking for the dev mailing list or bug report system (since it's not strictly an "Ubuntu-user" issue, but it's mostly related to the API).